# Java JSONObject getJsonArray Blank String

Tags: java, json

I have some JSON that is returned as follows:

```
[{"on_arrival_inst":"Ok","order_inst":"Ok","finished_inst":"Ok"},{"on_arrival_inst":"Arrive","order_inst":"Order","finished_inst":"Finished"}]
```

I am trying to split these into two arrays and get the strings out as follows:

```
jsonResultsObject = new JSONObject(result);
            jsonArray = jsonResultsObject.getJSONArray("");

            int count = 0;
            String onArrive, onReady, onFinished;

            while (count<jsonArray.length()){
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                onArrive = JO.getString("on_arrival_inst");
                onReady = JO.getString("order_inst");
                onFinished = JO.getString("finished_inst");

                System.out.println(onArrive);
                System.out.println(onReady);
                System.out.println(onFinished);

                count++;

            }
```

However the code never goes into the loop, as the array is not getting populated from the JSONObject?

Comment: check this statement `jsonResultsObject.getJSONArray("");`I think this is not correct. Ref : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf240/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

your result is JSONArray not JSONObject. That's why you must convert it to array not to object.

use

```
jsonResultsArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

instead of

```
jsonResultsObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

and the full code will be

```
        jsonResultsArray = new JSONArray(result);
        int count = 0;
        String onArrive, onReady, onFinished;

        while (count<jsonResultsArray.length()){
            JSONObject JO = jsonResultsArray.getJSONObject(count);
            onArrive = JO.getString("on_arrival_inst");
            onReady = JO.getString("order_inst");
            onFinished = JO.getString("finished_inst");

            System.out.println(onArrive);
            System.out.println(onReady);
            System.out.println(onFinished);

            count++;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@BigJimmyJones

The fact of that the code does not enter the loop is just because your `JSONArray` does not have a key named `""` but it contains `JSONObjects` instead. Objects and arrays in JSON have different annotations. See: [JSON Reference Website](http://json.org/)

So your code should be :

```java
jsonResultsObject = new JSONObject(result);

            String onArrive, onReady, onFinished;

            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                onArrive = JO.getString("on_arrival_inst");
                onReady = JO.getString("order_inst");
                onFinished = JO.getString("finished_inst");

                System.out.println(onArrive);
                System.out.println(onReady);
                System.out.println(onFinished);

            }
```

And also ensure that your code is inside a `try - catch` block to catch `JSONException`